# Workaround in UCanAccess for multi-value fields: "incompatible data type in conversion: from SQL type OTHER"?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, hsqldb, ucanaccess

I am trying to use UCanAccess to query a MS Access .accdb file.  Everything works great, except when I query multi-value fields.  For example those that have entries in the Row Source of a table field's Lookup tab in design view in MS Access.  My code crashes when I try to output the result:

```
ResultSet rslt = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT [singleValue], [multiValue] FROM [TableName];");
int count = 0;
while (rslt.next())
    System.out.println(count++ + "\t" + rslt.getString(1) + "\t" + rslt.getString(2));
```

The ResultSet is returned fine, and the singleValue prints fine, but the following error is thrown if I try to print the multiValue from the ResultSet:

> Exception in thread "main" net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: incompatible data type in conversion: from SQL type OTHER to java.lang.String, value: instance of org.hsqldb.types.JavaObjectData

I have tried querying a query that is stored in the .accdb, but that does not work, because it just triggers the original query, and returns the same ResultSet.

Am I missing something simple or is this something UCanAccess can not handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first question about it I have ever seen.
You can see an example of the complex types usage with UCanAccess in the ucanaccess web site, tab "Getting Started" (at the end of the page).
Here's a junit test case:
https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/code/HEAD/tree/ucanaccess/trunk/src/test/java/net/ucanaccess/test/ComplexTest.java
(see the testComplex method).

In particular you can't call `rslt.getString(2)`  but have to use `rslt.getObject(2)` .
You'll get a ucanaccess wrapper of your data.
If you wanted to get  string that described the data content you can use 
`rslt.getObject(2).toString()`.
The wrapping classes are:

```
net.ucanaccess.complex.Attachment,
net.ucanaccess.complex.SingleValue,
net.ucanaccess.complex.Version.
```

In your example,  `rslt.getObject(2)` should return an array of `net.ucanaccess.complex.SingleValue`.
Then you can call the method singleValue.getValue() on each array element to get the wrapped value.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try this.  I thought I had read the getting started page, but obviously not closely enough.  I figured it was something simple.  Thanks again for your help and patience.