# net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I am trying to read the data from an MS Access DB. 
Everything is going pretty fine. 
When it comes to multi-values fields, I get the following error.

Code:

```
String[] name = new String [50];
resultSet.getString("DummyColumn");
```

Error:

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4
>   incompatible data type in conversion: from SQL type OTHER to
>   java.lang.String, value: instance of org.hsqldb.types.JavaObjectData

I tried a work around by changing the code to this :

```
String[] name = new String [50];
name[i]=resultSet.getObject("DummyComun").toString();
```

Now I don't get the error but the result is in an unreadable format 
Something like this

```
[Lnet.ucanaccess.complex.SingleValue;@5c993e56
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373126/workaround-in-ucanaccess-for-multi-value-fields-incompatible-data-type-in-conv

Comment: Thanks for the help ..but I already looked into that thread and still I am getting
an unreadable result - SingleValue;@5c993e56